# Delete google maps perimeter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

how can I do a perimeter button wipe function on the map?

Is such a thing possible?

I want that after I drew the perimeter when I clicked on it to be deleted, but I don't really know how

I tried to make a method and after I put a click event but I will receive an "undefined" error. Maybe it can't be done what I want to do?

```
GmapMap
            ref="mapRef"
            :center="{lat:this.lat, lng:this.lng}"
            :zoom="zoom"
            map-type-id="terrain"
            :options="{
              scrollwheel: false,
              gestureHandling: 'greedy'
            }"
            style="width: 100%; height: 350px"
    >
        <gmap-polygon :paths="addressArea" ref="polygon" v-if="disableArea" :editable="this.editableArea" @paths_changed="updateEdited($event)"></gmap-polygon>
        <GmapMarker
           ref="marker"
          :position="{lat:this.latMarker, lng:this.lngMarker}"
          :clickable="true"
          :draggable="true"
          :editable="this.editableArea"
          @drag="updateCoordinates"
        />
    </GmapMap>


google.maps.event.addListener(vm.drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
      if (polygon.getPath().getLength() < 3) {
        alert('Area need 3 points.');
        polygon.getPath().clear();
        return;
      }
      vm.drawingManager.setOptions({
        drawingControl: false,
        drawingMode: null
      });
      vm.addressArea = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
        let point = polygon.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6)
        // point = point.replace(',',' ');
        point = point.split(',');
        vm.addressArea.push({lat: parseFloat(point[0]), lng: parseFloat(point[1])});
        // vm.addressArea.push(point);
      }
      // listeners for detecting geometry changes

      google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), "insert_at", function (){vm.updatePoints(polygon)});
      google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), "set_at", function (){vm.updatePoints(polygon)});
      google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), "remove_at", function (){vm.updatePoints(polygon)});
      google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), "dragend", function (){vm.updatePoints(polygon)});

    });

my method:
deletePerimter(polygon) {
        polygon.setMap(null);
     }
```

Comment: I see no PHP or Laravel here

Comment: I use Laravel mix.